# Генератор случайных чисел C

Tags: c, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь сгенерировать случайную строку, но она всегда получается состоящей из одинаковых символов

```
void random_password(char* p, short unsigned int lenght, char* symbols, short unsigned int border){
    for (short unsigned int i=0; i<lenght; i++){
        unsigned int s = random(0, border);
        p[i] = symbols[s];
    }
};

unsigned int random(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    srand(time(NULL));
    return a + rand()%b;
};
```

В качестве border пока передаю значение 10, вывод консоли на картинке. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать ГПСЧ с помощью переполнения, но тот тоже не давал приемлемых результатов (циклом выдавалось 9, 5, 7, 3)

Прошу, подскажите какой-нибудь более действенный алгоритм

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B вы снова и снова заставляете генератор генерировать одно и то же значение (в пределах секунды, потом секунду будет другое).

Вот это

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

вызывается
**ОДИН РАЗ**,
обычно в начале программы.

Comment: Действительно. Большое спасибо

Comment: Если ответ вас устроил — закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ щелчком по "птичке" слева.